# Is it possible to set up Heroku log drains to only "drain" application logs?

Tags: heroku, logging, loggly

I just set up a log drain to Loggly from my Heroku app, but Loggly is receiving my application logs (logs you'd see with `heroku logs --source app`) as well as the Heroku logs (logs you'd see with `heroku logs --source heroku`). Is there a way to set the drain so that only application logs are being sent to Loggly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to filter the drain.

Any filtering has to happen on the receiving end.

Comment: Thanks, by filtering on the receiving end do you mean filtering through the Loggly search itself? Or is there a configuration somewhere that allows that filter.

Comment: exactly. Assuming Loggly cannot filter the input stream, you have to filter when searching the logs.